# TypeScript static interface binding

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've asked a couple of questions related to extending static functionality of existing objects in JavaScript (using TypeScript). For the sake of all examples here, I am using `Object`

The following code demonstrates a polyfill definition for ECMAScript's `Object.is` function

```
Object.is = function(value1: any, value2: any): boolean {
    // ....impl
};  // ERROR : Property 'is' does not exist on type...
```

The reason for this is because `is` has not been implemented on `Object`, but we can make it visible like so

```
declare var Object: {
    is(value1: any, value2: any): boolean;
}
```

However the issue with this code is that this overwrites any existing static bindings (`bind`, `call`, `create`, `freeze` etc).

I understand that with recent versions of TypeScript, we can now statically bind interfaces *which are open-ended* to object declarations:

```
interface _Object {
    is(value1: any, value2: any): boolean;
}

declare var Object: _Object;
```

This is great because as pointed out, interfaces in TypeScript are open ended, thus I can continually bind more and more functionality into `Object`, however this does not correct the issue that once the interface is bound to `Object`, it overwrites the existing declaration, because [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/c9/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts) still declares `Object` like so:

```
declare var Object: {
    new (value?: any): Object;
    (): any;
    (value: any): any;
    prototype: Object;
    getPrototypeOf(o: any): any;
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o: any, p: string): PropertyDescriptor;
    getOwnPropertyNames(o: any): string[];
    create(o: any, properties?: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
    defineProperty(o: any, p: string, attributes: PropertyDescriptor): any;
    defineProperties(o: any, properties: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
    seal(o: any): any;
    freeze(o: any): any;
    preventExtensions(o: any): any;
    isSealed(o: any): boolean;
    isFrozen(o: any): boolean;
    isExtensible(o: any): boolean;
    keys(o: any): string[];
}
```

What I feel is needed here for the code in [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/c9/typescript/blob/master/typings/lib.d.ts) to be refactored to allow *open ended* interfaces to be bound statically to declarations, like so

```
interface _Object {
    new (value?: any): Object;
    (): any;
    (value: any): any;
    prototype: Object;
    getPrototypeOf(o: any): any;
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o: any, p: string): PropertyDescriptor;
    getOwnPropertyNames(o: any): string[];
    create(o: any, properties?: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
    defineProperty(o: any, p: string, attributes: PropertyDescriptor): any;
    defineProperties(o: any, properties: PropertyDescriptorMap): any;
    seal(o: any): any;
    freeze(o: any): any;
    preventExtensions(o: any): any;
    isSealed(o: any): boolean;
    isFrozen(o: any): boolean;
    isExtensible(o: any): boolean;
    keys(o: any): string[];
}

declare var Object: _Object;
```

Thus, when I create my interface for `Object.is`, and it's accompanying function, everything should work in harmony *<--- excuse the pun, (ECMAScript 6 code name)*

What I would like to know is, are there any plans fore future releases of TypeScript which will fix this issue, as suggested (or indeed any fixes which prove more efficient)?

Comment: This question should really be addressed to the TypeScript team here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since TypeScript 1.4 static extensions can be added easily. The TypeScript team changed the `lib.d.ts` file to use interfaces for all static type definitions.

The static type definitions are all named like `[Type]Constructor`: So if you want to add a static function to type `Object`, then add your definition to `ObjectConstructor`.

Definition:

```
interface ObjectConstructor
{
    is(value1: any, value2: any): boolean;
}
```

Implementation:

```
Object.is = function(value1: any, value2: any): boolean
{
    // your implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to know is, are there any plans fore future releases of TypeScript which will fix this issue, as suggested (or indeed any fixes which prove more efficient)?

Already raised here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/182